# variable/function declaration in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have several .cfm pages that make up my ColdFusion website.

In one of the .cfm page there is a variable/function used. This variable/function is named "RECREATE". I have checked that the current .cfm page does not have "RECREATE" defined. So, my question is how do I identify which cfm page is "RECREATE" defined??

Comment: look at all the included files and functions that are included on that page

Comment: Also...look in Application.cfm or Application.cfc (which ever is used) . You could also search the code base for other references to this function.

Comment: If you have debugging turned on, it shows all of the files that are called to display a page.  That list could be used to check for the location.  You could also use a regex search tool like grep to search for the declaration in all of the *.cfm files.

Comment: Yes, I have debugging on. I see a list of cfm files at top. So, this list of files are directly/indirectly used in displaying the content on the current page?

Answer (score 2):

Do a search in your source code for "recreate". Or if you have only "several" .cfm pages in the site... just look at them!

Your code, btw, should be engineered coherently enough that you can infer the location of code by what the code does, and how it is called. Sounds like you could do with some replanning / reorganisation?

Comment: Thank you, Adam. Yes, i would look into reorganizing the code.